# ¿Se puede detectar dos eventos de teclado a la vez?

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

en el siguiente código intento capturar dos eventos de teclado en js a la vez, como por ejemplo si el usuario esta presionando x y z a la vez muestre un mensaje que diga "¡¡¡Hola!!!". Gracias y aquí les dejo el código:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onkeydown="evento(event, even)" style="">
    <p id="parrafo"></p>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = document.getElementById("i");
        function evento(event, even){
            var x = event.key;
            var y = even.key;
            if(x == "x" && y == "z"){
                i.innerHTML = "¡¡¡Hola!!!";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Se que este codigo no funciona (ya lo probe), pero solo quería dar a entender lo que estoy buscando hacer.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! me ha servido :)

Comment: vaya, pues borré el comentario porque al releer tu pregunta pensé que me habia equivocado y que lo que querias era otra cosa, más bien inversa, je, lo siento. Vuelvo a poner los enlaces pues: 1) [Pregunta similar en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript), y 2) [Código de muestra sacado de sus respuestas](https://jsfiddle.net/B1KMusic/ofwa3pq2/). Saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cada vez que se pulsa una tecla se ejecuta el evento, una vez por tecla, de manera que para manejarlo debes guardarlas todas.
Una manera fácil es guardar las teclas pulsadas en un mapa, y eliminarlas al soltarlas, ya que podemos usar el código de la tecla como claves del mapa, y para comprobar si una tecla está siendo pulsada, solo hay que mirar si existe la clave que corresponda al código de la tecla.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var teclasPulsadas = new Map;

window.onkeydown = function(info){
    teclasPulsadas.set(info.code);
};

window.onkeyup = function(info){
    teclasPulsadas.delete(info.code);
};

function buclePrincipal(){
    var teclas="";
    teclasPulsadas.forEach((value, key)=>{teclas+=key+" ";});
    i.innerHTML=teclas;
    if (teclasPulsadas.has("KeyZ") && teclasPulsadas.has("KeyX")){
        i.innerHTML+=("<BR>Hola!");
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(buclePrincipal);
}
requestAnimationFrame(buclePrincipal);
```

```html
<div>Pulsa aquí dentro para probarlo.<div>
<div id="i"></div>
```

Para probarlo, pulsa primero dentro del snipet para que recoja los eventos de teclado.

Comment: Funciona muy bien. Quisiera una aclaración y si me permites una variación también. La variante sería definir `pulsandoTecla` con `let`. La aclaración, y aunque parezca infantil yo al menos no la sabía: no es necesario tomar el `id` con `const i = document.getElementById("i")`? Veo que no lo haces en el código y creía que era necesario capturar el elemento. Gracias!

Comment: Con let, la variable desaparecería al salir del "scoope", la idea es que sea una variable global para que cualquier función pueda consultarla.
Lo de usar directamente la id como objeto, lo hago para simplificar el código, y se que funciona, pero seguramente no guste a los "puristas".

Comment: Perdón si me expresé mal, no quise molestarte sino al contrario, no sabía siquiera que se podía tomar el id como objeto, por eso te lo consulté. No soy para nada purista, mas bien al contrario! Gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: Tranquilo, no lo digo por ti! Si no que ya me veo venir alguien quejándose ;-)
No me has molestado en absoluto :-)

Comment: Pues siendo "purista" debo informaros que la propiedad de lectura [keyCode está despreciada (deprecated)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) y no se aconseja su uso :-P

Comment: ¡Mecachis!
He actualizado el código de ejemplo.