# keydown JavaScript 2 teclas simultáneamente

Tags: javascript, keypressevent

Estoy tratando de que cuando se pulsen 2 teclas simultáneamente salga el mensaje de hola, si presiona una tecla si funciona, pero con 2 no, éste es mi código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Saludo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
      if (event.keyCode === 65 && event.keyCode === 66) {
        return console.log("hola");
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: KeyCode está deprecado, más información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). En su lugar, puedes usar `key` y especificar la letra de la tecla en vez de los números -> `event.key === "a" && event.key === "b"`.

Comment: Puedes encontrar la solución aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/540955/se-puede-detectar-dos-eventos-de-teclado-a-la-vez/540961#540961

Comment: @Cris223511.dev hice lo que dijiste pero no me funciona

Comment: @Mateo un poquito, no entiendo la explicación

Comment: No, no te va a funcionar, solo te comento que utilices el método de esa forma, ya que el `keyCode` está deprecado actualmente. Las soluciones lo encontrarás en los enlaces que te comentaban arriba, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos crear una especie de buffer usando un `Map`, y nos valemos de 3 eventos:

- `keydown` : Guardamos la tecla presionada
- `keyup`: Sacamos la tecla presionada del buffer
- `keypress`: Evaluamos la combinación de teclas

```js
const bufferKeys=new Map();
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => bufferKeys.set(event.code));
document.addEventListener("keyup", event => bufferKeys.delete(event.code));

document.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
 if(bufferKeys.has("KeyA") && bufferKeys.has("KeyB") ){
   console.log("HOLA");
 }
});
```

### Actualización.

[keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) está marcado como obsoleto

Basta con ocupar `keydown` en su lugar

```js
const bufferKeys=new Map();
document.addEventListener("keyup", event => bufferKeys.delete(event.code));
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  bufferKeys.set(event.code);
   if(bufferKeys.has("KeyA") && bufferKeys.has("KeyB") ){
   console.log("HOLA");
 }
});
```

Comment: Yussef, la pregunta es duplicada...

Comment: @Cris ya lo sabe. Pero su naturaleza es ayudar aunque las circunstancias no sean las más adecuadas.